# Help wording a popular sentiment

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I was asked to rate this translation and I'm on the fence. I realize it's clumsy and unnatural - needless to say, English isn't this person's first language and I'm helping them come up with a better version:

**Dear person is not the one you feel good with, but the one without whom you feel bad.**

My instinct is to change it to **The one dearest to you isn’t one who it’s nice to be with, but one who it’s horrible to be without**.

Comment: Your version is undoubtedly more conventional English than the original one. What specifcally about it do you want to ask about?

Comment: I guess I just wanted to make sure I’m not crazy. This person stands by their translation and it just doesn’t sound right to me.

Comment: Personally, I can name at least five things that are wrong with it.

Comment: Theirs might be a more direct translation. Without seeing the original (and it happening to be in a language some of us can understand), we can't say.  Grammatically the only problem with it is that "Dear person" needs an article or determiner; and "whom" makes it sound very old-fashioned (at least to me).

Comment: I agree with you 100%. Unfortunately, the original is in Russian. Aside from your points, I don’t like the syntax at all.

Comment: sure, but translations often use contorted syntax to retain details of the original. Whether to use contorted English and retain those details or clear English that might lose some details is a question of style, not grammar.

Comment: I mean, parts of it are grammatical, but I just find the whole thing unbalanced. It just doesn’t say it in my opinion.

Comment: I guess what I mean is that it doesn’t seem idiomatic. It doesn’t seem like something a native speaker would say.

Comment: Sure, but wordsmithing the translation, while retaining the original sense, is probably a better question for [Russian Stackexchange](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) than this one.

Comment: You’re probably right, I just wanted to get a true assessment of the actual translation attempt without influencing anyone with the original.

Comment: The problem isn't which version is better English (yours is). The problem is the original writer thinks theirs is better, which probably has to do with matching the sentiment of the original.

Comment: No doubt. By the way, both of us know Russian.

Comment: The first sentence is much better. Its simplicity gives it a kind of aphoristic or proverbial quality, like in that old song, *if you can’t be with the one you love, love the one you’re with*. The second sentence is more conventional, and has less impact on the mind.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be along the lines of the quote "Don’t be with someone you can live with, be with the person who you can’t live without." - which in turn is a modification of the original quote by Aleatha Romig "You don’t marry someone you can live with, you marry the person who you cannot live without."

In both your sentence and your friend's, "(A) dear person" means "A special person". Making that change gives that statement a lot more balance.

A special person is not the one whose presence makes you feel good, but the one whose absence makes you feel bad.